# Eclipse ui: retrieving the first visible line of an editor

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, editor

In the Eclipse UI, I'd like to set the visible area in an editor. In other words, if the number of lines of my file is larger than the number of lines my editor can show then I want to specify the first shown line. My first approach was to calculate the first visible line via the selection value of its vertical scroll bar. The following link points to my initial question.  Its answer explains how to set the first visible line in an editor.

[eclipse ui: setting scrollbar but editor does not follow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25159997/eclipse-ui-setting-scrollbar-but-editor-does-not-follow/25160394#25160394)

The problem now is that my initial way of retrieving the first visible line in an editor fails in some cases: Although I verify that the active page is indeed an editor, the focus might be assigned to another page. In such a case, the following code yields the ScrollBar of a different page:

```
public static void update(final IWorkbenchWindow w)
    final Scrollable scrollable = 
        (Scrollable) w.getWorkbench().getDisplay().getFocusControl();
    final ScrollBar vScrollBar = scrollable.getVerticalBar();
```

So, my question: If `editor` is the reference of an active editor (`ITextEditor` and `IReusableEditor`), how to I get its first visible line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can access the editor `ITextViewer` or its extension `ISourceViewer` (usually implemented by the `SourceViewer` or `TextViewer` class) you can call the `ITextViewer.getTopIndex()` method to get the top line index.

If your editor is derived from `AbstractTextEditor` (or one of its subclasses such as `TextEditor`) there is a protected method `getSourceViewer()` that returns this. You may have to add a `public` method if you want to access this from outside of the editor.